# "assets/index.html" not found in java implementation

Tags: java, satellizer

I am new to java and simply want to authenticate app through satellizer's java API, but it is not working. I tried to run [this satellizer example](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server/java), but it is giving an error: *assets/index.html not found*. There is no assets folder in the whole directory structure. I tried adding it. I also tried changing resource path from

```
 URL clientPage = Resources.getResource("assets/index.html");
```

to:

```
 URL clientPage = Resources.getResource("index.html");
```

by adding index.html in the path, but still same error. Has anyone else tried running this API?

Comment: Please, post the resulting error message.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Being new to java I didn't know about Maven's working. Its solution is every time when a change is made not only the java server will be restarted, maven is also needed to run. So every time I make changes I have to run two commands.

Firstly:

```
  mvn package
```

Secondly:

```
 java -jar target/dropwizard-example.jar server example.yml
```

Thanks to everyone took interest in the issue.

Comment: If this was the solution of your problem, please clarify that this is a real answer. It looks like any user has posted another problem as an answer. Also please accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

When using classpath resources the name of the package of the class is prepended to the actual path. That is the resource path is relative to the current class.

You have to use `/assets/index.html` with a slash at the beginning to identify that you want to access a resource from the root of the classpath.

Comment: yes it is a general problem but i cannot resolve it also tried what u said.".assets/index.html".even i change path as"index.html" it again says"assets/index.html" not found.

Comment: It sais "assets/index.html not found" even when you change your code to "/index.html"? Can you please post the resulting exception? And your current code?

Comment: my current code is same as 'assets/index.html'.The only change i made is running "mvn package" command after every change.